# ABC Model of Behaviour: What is an antecedent?

Tags: learning, behavior, behaviorism, conditioning

In the context of the three-term contigency what is meant by an antecedent and are there two types of antecendent - stimulus delta and stimulus discriminative? Why is it called the three-term contingency?

I would like to know if the below is correct. I am getting particularly confused about the distinction between an antecendent, a prompt, and a discriminative/delta stimulus.

My current understanding is that an antecedent is a setting event, action or object - it essentially just sets the occasion for a behaviour to occur.

Source: https://www.csus.edu/indiv/b/brocks/courses/eds%20245/handouts/week%205/classicalvopperant.pdf

The 2 types of antecedents are stimulus delta and stimulus discriminative.

A stimulus delta is a stimulus that signals unavailability of reinforcement, stimulus discriminative signals the availability of reinforcement.

Source: https://hopeeducationservices.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-discriminating-stimulus-sd-and-stimulus-delta-s%CE%B4/

Comment: You've asked a question, then proceeded to answer it in the same post, that's not precisely what we do here and has lead the automatic system to flag your question. Can you [edit] to make it clear what about your question is not answered by the two (commercial) links you include in it? Else your post may get deleted as spam. Please read our post: [how not to be a spammer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), though it's geared towards answers, it also applies to questions.